# Not able to install google apps after following the suggested steps

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, tablet

I have a retail tablet(Crystal Audio, GR) that after many tries I have managed to root it, with Kingo Root. I can the application SuperSu installed and when I am trying to perform root actions, it asks me for granting privileges. Everything godd, up here.

I have followed the steps described [here](http://senk9.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/how-to-install-google-apps-gapps-on-your-android-device-phone/) (moved apks to system and try to install them etc) but I cannot install them. After tapping the apks and clicking install, it returns with an error "Installation not done". I have tried to do it with adb, but I am not allowed to remount /system as rw(kernel issue?).

How to proceed? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You can pick the GApps archive from [Goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps) and flash them via custom recovery. For more details, please see [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Comment: Some questions here as I am not very familiar with the recovery screens. Is is supposed to be named as update.zip? My recovery has the following relevant options. "Apply update from ADB", "Apply update from TFCard", "Apply update from cache". Both the last 2, lead me to an empty dir with the only actual option being the "../" directory(one dir level up). How would you approach it?

Comment: Does your device have a custom recovery, or are you talking about the "stock recovery" it ships with? I'm not sure whether it's possible with the latter.

Comment: Stock one...lets say I am installing CWM recovery. Is it pretty easy then to flash the zip, I suppose? The problem is that I dont know how easy is to install a new recovery outside of Play store.

Comment: I'd say so, yes. CWM offers to "install update.zip from SDCard". For details on CWM, you can take a look at [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/clockworkmod/info) and [its most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod).

Comment: Thanks a lot...really helpful. Though I am experiencing the problem that my device is not officially supported

Comment: That would be a separate question ("how to install CWM on my xxx"), which of course you are free to ask! If you do so, please don't forget to include all the necessary details (brand/device, Android version, etc.). With some luck, someone else has a similar "combination", and can get you started on that.

Comment: BTW: Reading the blog you've linked, there might be a little misunderstanding. I never went the "manual way", but AFAIK you just need to 1) remount system read-write, 2) *copy* the `.apk` files to the corresponding directories indicated by the ZIP structure, 3) reboot. Have you tried that?

Comment: Wanted to...unfortunately I cannot remount /system as rw

Comment: The easiest way for that is probably the app [Mount /system](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.beansoft.mount_system). Alternatively, take a look at [How to mount system in rw mode if no custom recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25250/16575) or [How to remount / system as read - write in Android](http://ckirbach.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/how-to-remount-system-as-read-write-in-android/)

Comment: Ok, I did it...it was really easy. Boot on recovery, and ran adb sideload. Now I cannot see the apps in the menu but that's seem to be really different issue. Thanks for helping man

Comment: Why didn't I think of that option... If the apps work at least, you should make that an answer (it's perfectly fine to answer your own question!). With "menu" you mean the app-drawer, I guess? Still unusual they don't show up there. Can you add them to your homescreen (long-press an empty space, then select to add an app/shortcut)?

Comment: It is a little weird, I can see some necessary services  like Google Play Service, which werent exist previously, I cannot see any of the apps that are supposed to be installed. I will write an answer on that, and open an new thread as it seems a different issue. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that seemed to work, at last, was the following. I connected the tablet with USB into my PC. Then downloaded the signed package of gapps for my Android version, from http://Goo.im and moved it in the same dir as the adb executable.

After that, I booted the tablet in recovery mode, chose the option "Update from ADB", and run the command "adb sideload gapps.zip", where gapps.zip is the filename downloaded earlier. Everything run good and I can now see, the necessary services.